# Matplotlib: How to remove dark horizontal/vertical dots at the end of grid lines in?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to remove dark horizontal/vertical dots, at the end of grid lines?

Here is my Code:

```
ax3.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.grid(b=True, color=self.x_grid_line_color, linestyle='-')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, one way of doing it is by using `plt.tick_params(length=0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved the issue. I was referring to grid lines ending with a dark 1-2mm part. I wanted to remove that.

Comment: It helps to know what you're referring to when talking about this things. The 1-2 mm lines are not part of the grid lines, instead they are ticks, part of the axis objects. Happy plotting :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're probably referring to the axis tick marks, which are normally also visible when there are no grid lines. You can turn them off using `ax.tick_params()`:

```
ax3.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off')
```